# HTML5 implementation for Mobile Development

Tags: html, mobiledevice.framework

I want to implement `HTML5` for my apps to make it support for cross platform but I want to know what are all various Mobile Frameworks available and which one is best I can implement with.

I do aware of `PHONEGAP` and `MoSync`. My question is : any Framework apart from this available which could be best for implementation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PHONEGAP is a good mobile platform ... lots of plugins are available and cominity is growing so fast.

[**Here is a list of the plugins**](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins)

Also take care about performance ... [**LINK**](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/10/top-10-performance-techniques-for-phonegap-and-hybrid-apps-slides-available/)

Comment: Great! @Anri could you suggest me from where to start to learn about PHONE GAP as you are suggesting it as a best option.

Comment: this is a good article start from here http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/11/four-ways-to-build-a-mobile-app-part3-phonegap/